# Handwrite / draw on a text document

Tags: applications, google-play-store, text-editor

Is there an Android app that enables hand-writing / drawing on a word document? I want to draw and write on the text. I don't want to edit the document, but write on the top of it. Instead of typing the letters using the keyboard, I want to draw on the text. Just like writing / drawing on a picture, I would like to draw on a word document.

I have been looking for this everywhere, can anyone suggest me a good app that can do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is usually called "freehand drawing". I can't find any app that supports free hand drawing on Word document. However, Adobe Reader for Android supports freehand drawing annotation on PDF document. You can convert your word documents to PDF and use Adobe Reader to make your annotations.

Freehand annotation on an editable document like Word generally makes little sense anyway, because it's not always obvious where the annotation should move to when the text is edited.

Answer (score 1):

[Polaris Office](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.infraware.office.link) can open and edit word documents, and you can draw directly on the documents.

Comment: Not even a link to the app? And please don't "sign" your posts.

Answer (score 1):

A new version of [Microsoft's OneNote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.onenote) is out on Android (tablets only I'm afraid), which I think you can do exactly what you want. Type a text and handwrite over it. [Here's a blog post](http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/19/onenote-android-now-handwriting-support-full-tablet-experience-much-just-time-back-school/) describing the features.

I think that the best results are obtain with a Note tablet though, with an actual pressure sensitive electronic pen.